# Playing different songs when different images are clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a different audio file play according to the image that is clicked. However, right now only the speak audio file plays.

```
    <script>
        function play(){
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.play();
        }
        </script>
        <li>
        <img src="images/bark.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
        <audio id="audio" src="audio/speak.mp3" ></audio>
            </li>
            <script>
            function play(){
            var audio = document.getElementById("sit");
            audio.play();
            }
            </script>
            <li>
            <img src="images/sit.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
            <audio id="sit" src="audio/sit.mp3" ></audio>
            </li>
            <li>
```

Comment: Have you tried chaning one of the function names to `play_2` in the function and on the corresponding onclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using multiple functions for playing different audio files

```
<script>
    function playSpeak(){
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.play();
    }

    function playSit(){
        var audio = document.getElementById("sit");
        audio.play();
    }
</script>

<li>
    <img src="images/bark.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="playSpeak()">
    <audio id="audio" src="audio/speak.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/sit.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="playSit()">
    <audio id="sit" src="audio/sit.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
<li>
```

Or create a general function which can play different audios

```
<script>
    function playAudio(audioId){
        var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
        audio.play();
    }
</script>

<li>
    <img src="images/bark.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="playAudio('audio')">
    <audio id="audio" src="audio/speak.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/sit.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="playAudio('sit')">
    <audio id="sit" src="audio/sit.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
<li>
```

With prior example: [image]

Comment: Used the first version you said, works like a charm! Thanks, learned from this.

Comment: @Brandon Glad I could help :) Happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to play the different audio file according to the image that is get clicked.

```
      <script>
  function play(audioId){

    var sit = document.getElementById('sit');
    var bark = document.getElementById('bark');
    if (sit.duration > 0 && !sit.paused) {
       sit.pause();
       var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
       audio.play();

    } else if(bark.duration > 0 && !bark.paused){
       bark.pause();
       var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
       audio.play();
    }else{
       var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
       audio.play(); 
    }
  }
</script>
<li>
  <img src="images/bark.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play('sit')">
  <audio id="sit" src="audio/sit.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="images/sit.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play('bark')">
  <audio id="bark" src="audio/bark.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
```

Let me know, it is working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the similar function names. The program is not able to distinguish the two `play()` different play function, it just executes the first one that occurs!

```
<script>
function playSpeakAudio(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
}
</script>
<script>
function playSitAudio(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("sit");
    audio.play();
}
</script>

        <li>
        <img src="images/bark.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="playSpeakAudio()">
        <audio id="audio" src="audio/speak.mp3" ></audio>
        </li>

            <li>
            <img src="images/sit.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="playSitAudio()">
            <audio id="sit" src="audio/sit.mp3" ></audio>
            </li>
            <li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do

```
<script>
  function play(audioId){
    var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
    audio.play();
  }
</script>
<li>
  <img src="images/bark.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play('bark')">
  <audio id="bark" src="audio/speak.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="images/sit.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play('sit')">
  <audio id="sit" src="audio/sit.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
```

Comment: You can play any audio with a function with audio ID as the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function play(id){
        var audio = document.getElementById(id);
        audio.play();
    }
</script>

<li>
    <img src="images/bark.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play('audio')">
    <audio id="audio" src="audio/speak.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/sit.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play('sit')">
    <audio id="sit" src="audio/sit.mp3" ></audio>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function playSound(el,soundfile) {
if (el.mp3) {
    if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
    else el.mp3.pause();
} else {
    el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
    el.mp3.play();
}}


<span id="play-harmonium" title="Harmonium" onclick="playSound(this, 'audio/harmonium-play.mp3">
            <img src="img/pay-icon/mi_harmonium.png" name="Bottom-1" border="0" id="Bottom-1"/>
        </span>
        <span id="play-tabla" title="Tabla" onclick="playSound(this, 'audio/tabla-play.mp3">
            <img src="img/pay-icon/mi_tabla.png" name="Bottom-1" border="0" id="Bottom-1"/>
        </span>
        <span id="play-sitar" title="Indian Sitar" onclick="playSound(this, 'audio/indian-sitar-play.mp3">
            <img src="img/pay-icon/mi_indian-sitar.png" name="Bottom-1" border="0" id="Bottom-1"/>
        </span>
```